# Haskell Parsec - parsing two lists of stuff

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using [Advent of Code part 16](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/16) as an excuse to learn how to use Parsec, but I'm stumbling on how to handle this specific case.

The input is on the following format:

```
Before: [3, 2, 3, 0]
2 3 1 1
After:  [3, 2, 3, 0]

Before: [1, 0, 2, 1]
7 0 1 1
After:  [1, 1, 2, 1]

...

Before: [0, 0, 2, 1]
6 2 3 1
After:  [0, 6, 2, 1]



5 0 2 3
5 1 3 1
...
5 3 2 2
```

In other words, first a number of groups of three lines that parse into a structure, separated by blank lines, then three blank lines, then a number of lines of four digits.

I have working parsers for each of the structures - `Sample` and `MaskedOperation`, with parsers `sample` and `maskedOp` respectively<sup>1</sup> - but I can't figure out how to put them together to parse it into a `([Sample], [MaskedOperation])`.

I tried the following:

```
parseInput :: GenParser Char st ([Sample], [MaskedOperation])
parseInput = do
  samples <- sample `sepBy` (count 2 newline) <* count 3 newline
  operations <- maskedOp `sepBy` newline
  return (samples, operations)
```

but it fails when it reaches the three newlines, expecting another sample:

```
(line 3221, column 1):
unexpected "\n"
expecting "Before:"
```

How do I tell parsec that I want to take as many as it can, then consume the separator (the extra newlines), then start reading other stuff?

---

<sup>1</sup> Read the Advent of Code problem for context; the names are not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that you cannot use `sepBy` here.

Let's simplify it to parsing 'a' as samples and 'b' as newlines. You are going to parse strings like

`a b b a b b b c b c b c b`

So what does the parser think while traversing on such a string? Let's go through it:

---

> Parsing `a` or an empty sequence

`[a] b b a b b b c b c b c b`

> Oh, an `a`. The sequence is non empty, so I will parse `many` `"bb" >> "a"` from now.

`a [b b a] b b b c b c b c b`

> Success! Let's get some more or finish

`a b b a [b b] b c b c b c b`

> Okay, I have found another `bb`, so the sequence continues. Parsing `a`

`a b b a b b [b] c b c b c b`

> wat

---

The problem is that **parser won't rollback unless explicitly asked to do so**.
To give parser rollback ability you must mark it with `try` combinator, otherwise it won't be able to "unconsume" consumed input.

For now I don't see any better way than rewrite the `sepBy` combinator to make it aware that after parsing each separator it may need to return it back to the buffer if parsing `separator >> target` fails:

```
sepTry a sep = sepTry1 a sep <|> pure []
sepTry1 a sep = liftA2 (:) a (many (try $ sep *> a))
```

Note that parsing `a` must be included in `try` section – this is where the failure actually is triggered.

To visualize the difference let's see same scenario but with `sepTry` instead:

---

...

`a [b b a] b b b c b c b c b`

> Success! Let's **try** to get one more if possible

`a b b a ![b b] b c b c b c b`

> Okay, I have found another `bb`, so the sequence continues. Parsing `a`

`a b b a !b b [b] c b c b c b`

> Not what I expected. Return failure and move cursor to back exclamation mark.

`a b b a ![]b b b c b c b c b`

> Failed parsing `bba`, parsing sequence finished. Parse `bbb`

`a b b a [b b b] c b c b c b`

> Success!

---

In your case after each `Sample` this parser will attempt to read 2 newlines with `Sample` after them, or in case of failure 3 newlines and continue to `MaskedOperation`s

Answer (score 1):

What I did was run a tokenizing step first, and then use a `Parser String ([Sample], [Instruction])` instead of `Parser Char ([Sample], [Instruction])`. Having the list already tokenized made it a lot easier to ignore the whitespace and other irrelevant punctuation.

```
solve = parse . tokenize 
  where tokenize = concatMap words . lines . filter (not . (`elem` ",:[]"))
        parse = (,) <$> many sample <*> many instr
        sample = -- ...
        instr = -- ...
```

No backtracking is needed, because samples and instructions are distinguishable just from their first token.